# PHP general constants

Tags: php, constants

I understand that wanting to update or remove a constant is the exact opposite if what it is meant for, but here is my problem.

I want to be able to format a value in same same fashion that a constant does. i.e.: echo foo;

Where it can just be plain text, instead of echoing a variable like `$foo`.

It may seem like a silly thing to want to do, but I am hoping to create use out of it. However, if this is not possible, I guess that is that.

PS. I 'would' just define it as a constant, however I want it to be able to update (like re-defining it during a foreach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. The first one must be case-insensitive:

```
define("myConstant", "blah", true);
print myConstant; // blah
define("myConstant", "xxxx"); // No warning outputted
print myConstant; // xxxx
```

But, DON'T DO THIS! The whole point of a constant is that it's constant. Although you seem to sort of recognize this, what is wrong with that extra `$` sign, really, versus a much more clear code style?

Comment: I was hoping to make the usibility of the code as easy to understand to the end user. Typically I access one of my classes like such <?php echo $foo->bar ?> but it would be nice to just define that, and allow it to update since it would be in a foreach or while.

Comment: So, what is the actual purpose? Why do you need to change a constant?

Comment: I have another question if you dont mind: Do you know if there is a way to predefine a block of php code? like define 'echo "test"' or another chunk of code?

Comment: The only way that I know of is to use a function, and that's probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: @Earl.  If you just put echo "test"; in a file you can include it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#92327, you can redefine constants on the fly if necessary.

```
define("FIRST_CONSTANT", 'my 1st value', true);
echo FIRST_CONSTANT;
// my 1st value

define('FIRST_CONSTANT', 'my 2nd value');
echo FIRST_CONSTANT;
// my 2nd value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the name of a function like this:

```
<?php 
function hello(){ return "bla"; }
$a = hello;
$b = $a();
echo $b;
?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'd take him in the opposite direction of what he wants.